# How would I print the elements matching a regex pattern in order?

Tags: awk

I have a text file that has text in this format:

```
ptr[0] = Alloc(1)  returned 1000 (searched 1 elements)
Free List [ Size 1 ]:  [ addr:1001 sz:99 ] 

Free(ptr[0]) returned 0
Free List [ Size 2 ]:  [ addr:1000 sz:1 ] [ addr:1001 sz:99 ] 

ptr[1] = Alloc(7)  returned 1001 (searched 2 elements)
Free List [ Size 2 ]:  [ addr:1000 sz:1 ] [ addr:1008 sz:92 ] 

Free(ptr[1]) returned 0
Free List [ Size 3 ]:  [ addr:1000 sz:1 ] [ addr:1001 sz:7 ] [ addr:1008 sz:92 ] 

ptr[2] = Alloc(5)  returned 1001 (searched 3 elements)
Free List [ Size 3 ]:  [ addr:1000 sz:1 ] [ addr:1006 sz:2 ] [ addr:1008 sz:92 ] 

Free(ptr[2]) returned 0
Free List [ Size 5 ]:  [ addr:1000 sz:1 ] [ addr:1001 sz:5 ] [ addr:1006 sz:2 ] [ addr:1008 sz:8 ] [ addr:1016 sz:84 ]
```

And I am trying to print out only the values that match with the `sz:` in the text file and print them in the order they are in but as a list. Like so:

```
$ awk -f list.awk file.txt | head
99
1 99
1 92
1 7 92
1 2 92
1 5 2 8 84
```

I've tried the following, but it prints out only the lines that contain `sz:`. How could I break it further to get the output I want?

```
/Free List/{
s = $0
split(s, a, /sz:/)
print s
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following `awk` solutions may help you on same.

***Solution 1st:*** When you want only digit value associated with string `sz` then following may help you on same.

```
awk '{while(match($0,/sz:[0-9]+/)){val=(val?val FS:"") substr($0,RSTART+3,RLENGTH-3);$0=substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)}}val!=""{print val;val=""}'  Input_file
```

Adding a non-one liner form of solution too now.

```
awk '
{
  while(match($0,/sz:[0-9]+/)){
    val=(val?val FS:"") substr($0,RSTART+3,RLENGTH-3);
    $0=substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)}
}
val!=""{
  print val;
  val=""
}
'  Input_file
```

***Solution 2nd:*** In case you need to have string `sz` also with values then following may help you on same.

```
awk '{while(match($0,/sz:[0-9]+/)){val=(val?val FS:"") substr($0,RSTART+3,RLENGTH-3);$0=substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)}}val!=""{print val;val=""}' Input_file
```

Adding a non one liner form of solution too now.

```
awk '
{
  while(match($0,/sz:[0-9]+/)){
    val=(val?val FS:"") substr($0,RSTART+3,RLENGTH-3);
    $0=substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)}
}
val!=""{
  print val;
  val=""
}
'  Input_file
```

***NOTE:*** In case you want to perform this operation only on those lines which havd string `Free List` then add `/Free List/{` before `while` and add `}` before `'` in above solutions simply.

Comment: @EdMorton, awesome Ed sir, thanks a TON, made the changes now, cheers :)

Comment: You're welcome. It'll still fail if sz:0 appears though since you should be testing `val!=""` rather than just `val` (or even better reverse the logic to avoid testing a negative).

Answer (score 1):

if `perl` is okay:

```
$ perl -lne 'print join " ", /sz:(\d+)/g if /Free List/' ip.txt
99
1 99
1 92
1 7 92
1 2 92
1 5 2 8 84
```

- `if /Free List/` if line contains `Free List`

  - `/sz:(\d+)/g` match all digits that follows `sz:`
  - `print join " "` print those matches separated by space
- see https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#Command-Switches for details on `-lne` options

Answer (score 0):

Using bash and grep:

```
while IFS= read -r line; do
    x=$(grep -oP '(sz:\K\d+)' <<< "$line")
    [[ $x ]] && echo $x
done < file
```

### Output :

```
99
1 99
1 92
1 7 92
1 2 92
1 5 2 8 84
```

Answer (score 0):

With GNU awk for FPAT:

```
$ awk -v FPAT='sz:[0-9]+' '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) printf "%s%s", substr($i,4), (i<NF?OFS:ORS)}' file
99
1 99
1 92
1 7 92
1 2 92
1 5 2 8 84
```

With any awk:

```
$ awk '{out=""; while (match($0,/sz:[0-9]+/)) { out = (out=="" ? "" : out OFS) substr($0,RSTART+3,RLENGTH-3); $0=substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH) } $0=out } NF' file
99
1 99
1 92
1 7 92
1 2 92
1 5 2 8 84
```